# List Insertion Governance Limitation

Tags: apex

Is there any difference in the DML between these 2 approaches? The below example only has 3 records to insert. But assume we have a larger number. The 2 approach would technically insert exactly the same number of records. But the List insertion is preferred....why is this?

```
List<SObject> list1 = new List(){record1,record2, record3};
insert list1;
```

vs

```
insert record1;
insert record2;
insert record3;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<SObject> list1 = new List(){record1,record2, record3};
insert list1;
```

The above will basically run the trigger/Flows once, if all the records are of same object type. Which is as per best practice.

Which mean: If you insert one record or multiple records of same sobject type in a list, the triggers/Flows etc will only run once.

The later :

```
insert record1;
insert record2;
insert record3;
```

will run the triggers/flows thrice in the same transaction. Which means it consumes  3 times more governor limits than prior.

Which mean: If you write the insert statement thrice, the triggers/flows will run 3 times and consume those many limits.